# How to find continuous functions that demonstrate that the set $\{(x,y):y>x\}$ is open and connected?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Consider the set of points $U$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ that lie above the line $y = x$, i.e. points $(a,b)$ such that $b>a$. Prove that $U$ is open and connected.

The method that is recommended is showing that there is a continuous function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ that is the inverse of $U$.

This is pretty difficult for me and I don't know how to go about proving this. Can someone explain to be the most basic and intuitive proof?

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = y - x > 0$. For connectedness, use the fact that intervals are connected and continuous functions map from connected sets into connected sets.

Comment: You are confused at the most basic level: $U$ is a subset of $R^2$, not a function, so talking about the inverse of $U$ makes no sense. Start by thinking about relation of continuous functions and open sets. This will explain why your subset is open.

Comment: Studious, I wasn't confused. I know that U is some open set and not a function. I was just a little sloppy posting the question. I thank you for the help though, man. I'm going to ponder on wht you said.

Comment: Being "just a little sloppy" makes that each reader wonders what you might mean by a continuous function inverse of an open set. Something to avoid, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R},\quad f(x,y)=y-x.$$
Then, $f$ is continuous and $(0,\infty)$ is open, so
$$f^{-1}((0,\infty))=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y>x\}=U$$
is open. Now, let
$$g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2,\quad g(x,y)=(x,x+e^{y}).$$
Then, $g$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, so
$$g(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:y>x\}=U$$
is connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can argue in this way: your set $U$ is homeomorphic to the open upper plane $\{(a,b), b>0\}$ via a rotation of angle $\pi/4$. Now, this is open, since it can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{(x,y), x\in\mathbb{R}, 0<y<n\}$, and every set in this union is obviously open. Now, for connectedness, it's more! It's path connected, you can link any two points in the upper plane by a segment entirely contained in the upper plane.